# Local storage not working properly for JS onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, local-storage

My local storage works in terms of saying true and false, but when the page is refreshed, it reverts but keeps the value. For example, if I switch from default darkmode (false) to lightmode (true), it shows as true in the local storage (which is good). However, when I refresh the page, although the value still is true, the page has reverted to its default (false).

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="stored()">
  <label for="ID_HERE" class="toggle-switchy">
    <input checked type="checkbox" name="server" id="ID_HERE" />
    <span class="toggle" onclick="toggle()" id="saveDarkLight"></span>
    <span class="switch"></span>
  </label>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
function stored() {
  var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("server");
  if (storedValue) {
    lightmode()
    document.getElementById("ID_HERE").checked = true;
  } else {
    darkmode()
    document.getElementById("ID_HERE").checked = false;
  }
}

function toggle() {
  if (document.getElementById("ID_HERE").checked) {
    lightmode()
    var input = document.getElementById("ID_HERE");
    localStorage.setItem("server", input.checked);
  }
  else {
    darkmode()
    var input = document.getElementById("ID_HERE");
    localStorage.setItem("server", input.checked);
  }
}

function darkmode() {
  const bodyChanges = document.querySelectorAll('.margin_body');
  for (let i = 0; i < bodyChanges.length; i++) {
    bodyChanges[i].style.background = '#0c0a0f';
  }
}

function lightmode() {
  const bodyChanges = document.querySelectorAll('.margin_body');
  for (let i = 0; i < bodyChanges.length; i++) {
    bodyChanges[i].style.background = 'white';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage` only saves `string` values, so saving `true` or `false` will convert it to `'true'` or `'false'`.
When you read back, you need to either `JSON.parse` it or check against the string values.

```js
function stored() {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem("server");
    if(storedValue === 'true'){  // <------
        lightmode()
        document.getElementById("ID_HERE").checked = true;
    }else{
        darkmode()
        document.getElementById("ID_HERE").checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'checked')
This is at: document.getElementById("ID_HERE").checked = true;

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I think you'll want the onclick event handler on the input element.

Also, the following is a quick and dirty implementation:

JS:

```
const SAVED_USER_INPUT = "savedUserInput";
const TARGET_ID = "toggle-text";
const BLUE = "blue";
const RED = "red";
const text = {
  [BLUE]:
    "Text color currently set to blue (default/unchecked state). Click to change to red",
  [RED]: "Text color currently set to red. Click to change to blue",
};

const handleToggle = (event) => {
  const isChecked = event.target.checked;
  const color = isChecked ? RED : BLUE;
  setColor(color);
  setText(color);
  savePreference(color);
};

const setColor = (fontColor = BLUE) => {
  document.getElementById(TARGET_ID).style.color = fontColor;
  return true;
};
const setText = (color) => {
  document.getElementById(TARGET_ID).innerText = text[color];
  return true;
};
const setChecked = (color) => {
  if (color === RED) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].setAttribute("checked", true);
  }
};
const savePreference = (color) => localStorage.setItem(SAVED_USER_INPUT, color);
const getSavedPreference = () => localStorage.getItem(SAVED_USER_INPUT);
// localStorage.clear()
window.onload = () => {
  if (!(getSavedPreference() === null)) {
    const savedColor = getSavedPreference();
    setColor(savedColor);
    setText(savedColor);
    setChecked(savedColor);
  } else {
    setColor();
    setText(BLUE);
    setChecked(BLUE);
  }
};
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>localStorage</title>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="handleToggle(event)">
        <span id="toggle-text"></span>
        </span>
    </label>
</body>

</html>
```